# Detect closed region corona labs

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am working o this app. In which you have to trap a ball in desired area you can add/remove object by touching a box so that you can trap the ball. As you can see in the picture the green region is the area where user have to trap a ball.

I am able to detect a trap if it's done in that region but what i want to do is also detect if user trap ball in some other region as you can see in the below picture red ball is trapped. So any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Not clear whatyou mean. Perhaps if you posted the code that currently determines trapping, and clarified what you tried to extend this, we can help.

Comment: please check this post i have posted it you can detail on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25867647/find-close-path-or-region-using-recursive-method/25867913?noredirect=1#25868314